# Most reliable way of determining whether html content is "complete"?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have an app that can receive two types of HTML content; either fragmentary (ie, not wrapped in `<html>` and not having a `<head>`) to be injected into a `div` or complete HTML to be injected into an `iframe`. I want to tell the difference between the two kinds of content.

My first thought is to use a regular expression to look for an an  tag, but I need one that won't be fooled by the various ways it could be formed, nor by text in the . What's the most reliable way of doing this? I was hoping for a general language-neutral answer, but the function will almost certainly be written in javascript.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this. It’s not quite clear why you need to know this. If you’re going to insert HTML, you would select some part of it anyway. E.g. `const domParser = new DOMParser(); const desiredElement = domParser.parseFromString(yourHTMLString, "text/html").querySelector(desiredSelector); theDiv.replaceChildren(...desiredSelector.childNodes);`. It doesn’t matter whether it’s a full HTML document or not. Consider using [<template>s](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Comment: "_a general language-neutral answer_" The used language depends on the environment you'll run this, the environments offer the best solutions for the problem, unless you're not going to write your own HTML parser. If you can control the data source, the simplest way would be to response with JSON, one property for the type (document/fragment) and another for the actual response text (the markup).

Comment: Note that the `<head>` and `<html>` tags are actually optional. `<!DOCTYPE html><title>Test</title>` is a valid, complete HTML document. The `<title>` tag is optional, too, if it’s the `srcdoc` of an `<iframe>`. The minimal, valid HTML for an `<iframe>` is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.